# Convert Two Dimentional Array To Graph

Tags: java, arrays, graph, breadth-first-search, depth-first-search

I have a two dimentional array as example below that determine Distance
how can I Convert Array elements to Graph's nodes
also I want to keep Up,Down,Right & Left of each node
(my main purpose is to use bfs , dfs , A* and others on this array)
S is root

```
# # # #
# S . #
# . . #
# # # #
```

Comment: what is your graph data structure? what have you tried so far?

Comment: Some data structure that can be traversed by bfs , dfs , A* and etc

Comment: Then you can use some library that provides that data structure, which you can find using google, or you can implement your own.  In any case, SO is not a free coding service, read [ask], if you dont show any effort and/or provide more details, we can't help.

Comment: @saljuama sorry , thanks

Comment: dont take me wrong, its a feedback comment, its like saying, help us to help you :)

Comment: @saljuama in fact I solved that in some way by adjacency matrix , but I want to check all path from one node but bfs just check a node once and if it was in another path after Once it will ignored, can you help me,thanks